# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'm.lib'

Tags: ros, c++, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile the old PR2 libraries to run on ROS on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 19.

One of the dependencies `ivcon` fails to compile giving the following error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'm.lib`

I searched for an answer and I understand the main issue is one of C programs calling for `m.lib` that is not present.
I tried to replace the library named 'msvcrt' with m as suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121570 but it didn't work.

Appreciate to get any advise on how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392236/link-:-fatal-error-lnk1104:-cannot-open-file-%27m.lib%27/) by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some digging, removing `m.lib` from LINK_LIBRARIES  located in the `build.ninja` file in the `build` folder fixed the problem, and I was able to compile successfully.

```
#############################################
# Link the executable C:\ivcon_ws\devel\lib\ivcon\ivcon.exe

build C$:\ivcon_ws\devel\lib\ivcon\ivcon.exe: C_EXECUTABLE_LINKER__ivcon_RelWithDebInfo ivcon\CMakeFiles\ivcon.dir\src\ivcon.c.obj
  FLAGS = /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
  LINK_FLAGS = /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console
  LINK_LIBRARIES = kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
  OBJECT_DIR = ivcon\CMakeFiles\ivcon.dir
  POST_BUILD = cd .
  PRE_LINK = cd .
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = ivcon\CMakeFiles\ivcon.dir\
  TARGET_FILE = C:\ivcon_ws\devel\lib\ivcon\ivcon.exe
  TARGET_IMPLIB = C:\ivcon_ws\devel\lib\ivcon.lib
  TARGET_PDB = C:\ivcon_ws\devel\lib\ivcon\ivcon.pdb
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0